# Best way to get rows between specific month

Tags: mysql

I have a date being passed to my script in the format as yyyy-mm-dd.

I'm trying to grab all journal entries that fall within the month and year provided.

Should I just do this, where yyyy-mm is the date provided?

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE ts_date > yyyy-mm-01 AND ts_date < yyyy-mm-31

Seems like there might be a more efficient way of handling this.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ts_date BETWEEN yyyy-mm-01 AND yyyy-mm-31`

Comment: ugh always forget about between.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
-- Finds records from January
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(ts_date) = 1 AND YEAR(ts_date) = 2012;
```

Comment: can Year be factored here too?

Answer (score 1):

I generally use BETWEEN syntax handling long queries seem easy to me that way.

So you can use it like this;

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE ts_date BETWEEN '2010-11-18' AND
>   '2011-02-17'

(i guess using sample dates is better than using date syntaxes :) )

And if you need to use dates put in the string fields (which must avoided.)

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(ts_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN
>   '2010-11-18' AND '2011-02-17')